# Firebase/MLVisionTextModel is not getting installed via pods iOS

Tags: firebase, machine-learning, text-recognition

[!] CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "Firebase/MLVisionTextModel":
  In Podfile:
    Firebase/MLVisionTextModel

Specs satisfying the `Firebase/MLVisionTextModel` dependency were found, but they required a higher minimum deployment target.

Answer (score 1):

Okay!

I have faced the issue yesterday and couldn't solve the issue after trying `pod repo update` or `pod install` or `pod install` after `pod deintegrate` etc.

I simply have a option , I deleted the `Podfile.lock`, then in `Podfile` I simply made pod versions fixed (so that other members of my team aren't affected) i.e. I used `SDWebImage` like

`pod 'SDWebImage', '3.8', :inhibit_warnings => true`

then run `pod install`

only that time it worked for me and saved the whole day!